# Smell rancid or smell Rancidity

Tags: grammar, word-choice

"you should check the oil bottle if you smell rancid/rancidity. Don't use it"
The proofreader says rancid, but i would say rancidity

Comment: You should check the oil if **it smells** rancid. (There's probably nothing wrong with either you or the bottle.)

Answer (score 1):

You could say:

*"You should check the oil for rancidity. If the oil smells rancid do not use it."*

or just: "*If the oil smells rancid do not use it."*

> rancidity (noun): the condition or state of being rancid
>
> rancid (adjective): (of butter, oil, etc.) tasting or smelling unpleasant because ofnot being fresh